# Bing Web Search API stopped working?

Tags: azure, bing

The Bing Web Search API worked last week and at some point this week, it has been returning 403 errors.  I don't know if anyone else has been encountering similar problems?

To replicate this, simply signup [here](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search) with a bing account and you should get 5000 free queries per month.  Below is a snippet of code (I believe I'm properly authenticated since putting in improper credentials fails gives a 401, rather than 403 error).

```
import requests
user = '...'
key = '...'

# 403 error
requests.get('https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27Xbox%27&$format=json', auth=(user, key))

# 401 error
requests.get('https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27Xbox%27&$format=json', auth=('a', 'b'))
```

Is anyone else getting this?

Comment: 403 is the "Forbidden" status code. Your subscription probably expired or you exhausted the available queries

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding!  I created a new account to test this so I thought I ruled it out but upon retesting, I found out that this was not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 is the `Forbidden` status code. Your subscription probably expired or you exhausted your query limit.

Server errors are always in the 500-599 range. Errors in the 400-499 range are always client errors. If you repeatedly receive `500` errors, you should check [Azure's status page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) to ensure there isn't a problem.

As a rule, you shouldn't assume that a major service like Bing Search is down and no-one noticed for days. It's far more likely that there is a problem with your account or your code, especially if you receive client error codes.